# Hyperlink URL is getting appended with the localhost application URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my HyperLinkField in the gridview.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="prod_url" DataTextField="prod_url"   Target="_blank" HeaderText="URL" DataTextFormatString="https://{0}"/>
```

Prod_url is the URL that i am getting from the datatbase. Problem is when i click on hyperlink, the URL is getting appended with my localhost application url.
Ex: prod_url = www.google.com
when i click on hyperlink, URL taking it as 
http://localhost:20648/Application_Details/www.google.com
I do not know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are formatting the `DataTextFormatString` when you should be formatting the `DataNavigateUrlFormatString`.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFormatString="https://{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="prod_url" DataTextField="prod_url" Target="_blank" HeaderText="URL" />
```